# Calculate compounding factor

Tags: r

I have a set of data as follow and want to calculate the compounding factor for each of the items based on the Duration column.
The condition is that Duration is a multiple of 12, then I will apply a factor.
For example, item 2 has Duration starts from M34 to M37, I will apply a factor to M36.

However, the tricky part is I dont want to apply any factor if the first element in Duration vector for each item is a multiple of 12. For example, Item 1 starts from M24 to M27. Even though M24 is a multiple of 12, I dont want to apply any factor here.

This is my original dataset:

```
          ID               Rate.1    Duration
 1:       1                0.0200      M24
 2:       1                0.0200      M25
 3:       1                0.0200      M26
 4:       1                0.0200      M27
 5:       2                0.0200      M34
 6:       2                0.0200      M35
 7:       2                0.0200      M36
 8:       2                0.0200      M37
 9:       2                0.0200      M48
```

What I want is Rate.2 col below:

```
          ID               Rate.1    Duration      Rate.2
 1:       1                0.0200      M24            1
 2:       1                0.0200      M25            1  
 3:       1                0.0200      M26            1
 4:       1                0.0200      M27            1
 5:       2                0.0200      M34            1
 6:       2                0.0200      M35            1
 7:       2                0.0200      M36            1.2 
 8:       2                0.0200      M37            1.2
 9:       2                0.0200      M48            1.44
```

Is there a neat solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not overly neat. Edited solution without loop:

```
df=data.frame("ID"=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,5)),
         "Rate.1"=rep(0.02,9),
         "Duration"=paste0("M",c(24:27,34:37,48))
  )

ids = which(as.numeric(sub("M","",df$Duration[-1]))%%12 == 0)+1
df$Rate.2 =  1
df$Rate.2[ids]=1.2
df$Rate.2=cumprod(df$Rate.2)

df
      ID Rate.1 Duration Rate.2
    1  1   0.02      M24   1.00
    2  1   0.02      M25   1.00
    3  1   0.02      M26   1.00
    4  1   0.02      M27   1.00
    5  2   0.02      M34   1.00
    6  2   0.02      M35   1.00
    7  2   0.02      M36   1.20
    8  2   0.02      M37   1.20
    9  2   0.02      M48   1.44
```

Previous solution with for loop:

```
df$Rate.2 =  1
    ids = which(as.numeric(sub("M","",df$Duration))%%12 == 0)
    for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
      if(i%in%ids){
        df$Rate.2[i:nrow(df)]=df$Rate.2[i:nrow(df)]*1.2
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works but I was hoping for a solution that doesn't involve using loops as the actual dataset has more than 300000 rows so it does take a long time to run.

Comment: New solution without for loop. Any better?

Comment: Much better now. Thank you. You save me a lot hours

Comment: I am glad @southwind. Please tick to accept the answer if it worked :)